# If else statement not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs depending on the parent div being X pixels from the top of the window...

```
        if (chartContainer <= 700) {

            $('.firstChart').addClass('rotateLeft');
            $('.firstChart').animate({'left': 30}, 600);
            $('.secondChart').addClass('rotateRight');
            $('.secondChart').animate({'right': 30}, 600);

        } else if (chartContainer > 700) {

            $('.firstChart').removeClass('rotateLeft');
            $('.firstChart').animate({'left': -300}, 600);
            $('.secondChart').removeClass('rotateRight');
            $('.secondChart').animate({'right': -300}, 600);

        }
```

My function is adding the class fine, but its not running the animate on neither, If I remove my else statement, the add class and animate in the first block of code runs perfectly, can anybody see anything wrong syntax wise?

------- JS Fiddle ---------

http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Fv/1/

Comment: Does the element have a position (other than static) and a left value set to begin with.

Comment: Just thinking: May be you must change `300` to `30` in `else` statement.

Comment: I can see something wrong logic-wise: `if A, else if not A`.

Comment: Syntax looks good, can you console.log(chartContainer) ? Is this your real code or just a part of it ? Any other if/else on your code ? You can add your full code in jsfiddle. This part of your code has no pb imo

Comment: Added a fiddle @PierreGranger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to reach something like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/8QFzd/2/

IE 2 blocks out of screen (left and right hidden), when you scroll near to them they comme to center of the screen ?

```
var state = 1 ;

$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() ;
    var chartContainer = ($('.chartContainer').offset().top - scrollTop);

    console.log(chartContainer);

    if (chartContainer <= 200) {
        if ( state != 1 )
        {
            console.log('<= 200, add Class & animate') ;
            state = 1 ;
            $('.firstChart').addClass('rotateLeft');
            $('.firstChart').stop().animate({
                'left': 30
            }, 600);
            $('.secondChart').addClass('rotateRight');
            $('.secondChart').stop().animate({
                'right': 30
            }, 600);
        }

    } else {
        if ( state != 2 )
        {
            console.log('> 200, remove Class & animate') ;
            state = 2 ;
            $('.firstChart').removeClass('rotateLeft');
            $('.firstChart').stop().animate({
                'left': -300
            }, 600);
            $('.secondChart').removeClass('rotateRight');
            $('.secondChart').stop().animate({
                'right': -300
            }, 600);
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `.animate` to complete and then fire the next part.

For the `else` block.

```
$('.firstChart').removeClass('rotateLeft');
$('.firstChart').animate({'left': -300}, 600, function(){
    $('.secondChart').removeClass('rotateRight');  
    $('.secondChart').animate({'right': -300}, 600);
});
```

Same for the `if` block.

P.S. Make your `else if` part be just `else`. And, make sure that your elements have a positioning which is not static, else this code might not work.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurang Tandon, the second chart element doesn't need to run after the first chart however, they both need to run at the same time

Comment: Ok, could you please share your full HTML code, and CSS, along with whole JS code, and possibly in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I see two errors: 1) There's no styling at all for the `.rotateLeft` class. So adding and remove such a class doesnt make any difference. 2) Your containers have a `static` position (by default). Set their `position` property to `relative`.

Comment: Still no luck @Gaurang Tandon, I've added my CSS too so you can see it all exactly http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Fv/1/

Comment: [Working](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Gm9Fv/3/) ! 1) moved the `left`, `right` offset animation into CSS. 2) Added transition property. 3) Removed `-webkit-animation` properties (because its existence didn't make any change in the effect)